# botocore.errorfactory.InvalidS3ObjectException

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have aws recognition code written in Python, and it run's by Node API, which works fine on Windows system but when I'm deploying it on Linux I'm facing this issue:- `botocore.errorfactory.InvalidS3ObjectException: An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the DetectText operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.`

I have given both AmazonRekognitionFullAccess and AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess access role to I'm user. Still I don't know how to get things going.

Python code:-

```
bucket = 'image-test'
def image_to_dict(fileName, bucket):
    client = boto3.client('rekognition', 'us-east-2')
    response = client.detect_text(Image = { 'S3Object': { 'Bucket': bucket, 
    'Name': fileName } })
    return response
```

Node Code used to run Python script:-

```
var options = {
            mode: 'text',
            pythonPath:"/usr/bin/python2.7"
            pythonOptions: ['-u'],
            scriptPath: "/home/ubuntu/test",
            args: [imageURl]
        };
        PythonShell.run('script.py', options, function (err, results) {
            if (err)
                throw err;

        console.log("Data is: "+results)
```

I have Python version 2.7 installed on my Ubuntu, pip version 10.0.1.

Comment: I assume everything you're working with is in us-east-2, correct?

Comment: yes, iam using region us-east-2

Comment: What about individual file permissions? Your bucket may allow read-only access, but do the individual files in your bucket allow your user to look at them? I had a similar problem with viewing a static website a while back.

Comment: I have kept bucket access permission as public. Even my user have Admin access so it won't be a issue I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

The reason behind the issue was, when i was passing image name as argument from Node API, the name was getting manipulated due to some Substring logic.So when python script goes with that manipulated name to search in S3 bucket, it used to through above error as that name was not existing in the S3 bucket.